# Rendering price in Grid output

Tags: renderer

The code I am using is:

```
    $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total'),
        'index' => 'grand_total',
        'filter_index' => 'sfo.grand_total',
        'type' => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'order_currency_code'
    ));
```

This should render the price as [£/$][00.00] and not as 000.0000 as it is now. How do I make it to two decimal places?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$this->addColumn('grand_total',array(
    'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total'),
    'index' => 'grand_total',
    'type'  => 'price',
    'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode()
));
```